# Aspx.cs doesn't recognize controls declared in aspx ?! - CS0103

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, master-pages

I am working on a project in asp.net C# where debugger shows the following error
CS0103 [The name does not exist in the current context]

I tried to delete my aspx.cs file and regenerate it again.
I have a feeling what cause the problem is masterpage

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddEmployee.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddEmployee" Title="test" MasterPageFile="~/AdminMaster.master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
```

my `html + css + js` code is within `ID="Content1"` tag do you think this what cause the problem ?

**Update**

This is from my `AddEmployee.aspx`

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" class="effect" id="FirstName" placeholder="FirstName" required="required" runat="server" />
```

I have about 8 `asp:Textbox` and the debugger shows error it these 8 the following is an example of the error

> State Error   CS0103  The name 'FirstName' does not exist in the current context

**Update: half way solution**

I tried the following I take a copy of my master page code and  past it to targeted .aspx page

So I am running the page without master page and guess what it works now

So what should I do to make it work with master page ?

Comment: Is there a reason why there is a > before MasterPageFile?  Is that in the code or just a typo in this question?

Comment: it's not there in my code I was trying to put the whole code in a block

Comment: Ok, thanks, wanted to make sure it was a typo in the question, not your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your TextBox doesn't have the right closing tag of TextBox
Thats how it should be done:

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" class="effect" id="FirstName" placeholder="FirstName" required="required" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

1. you should check out if the TextBox FirstName is exist in your design file of the aspx... that might cause the problem
2. check out that you closed the tag of Content2

it would be helpful if you will put all your aspx code in here.

Comment: could you check the part that I have added [Update: halfway solution]
I mentioned that I solved the problem but still not on the way that I want it.
my solution was to abandon using master page. which I think it's a bad idea because it means I will repeat both header & footer on all pages. If there is a way to not repeat header & footer without using master page please feel free to help me out

Comment: I think you might have a bug in your master page code... but I can't do nothing without it I need to see it

Comment: Omer Eli I can't add my master page code it's more than 500 line and here the max is 600 I think. I will put the main structure to give an idea about it

Comment: ok, I am about to give up using master page

this comment taken from a user: Dan 


    I realized that if I have a asp:Content tag on my page with the contentplaceholderID set to the ID for the content placeholder in the master page that I will never be able to access any controls in the content placeholder. The asp:Content page is always merged with the MasterPage content, even if the asp:Content tag is empty on your content page. To provide the default content, I moved my label outside of the content placeholder tag and set the visibility to false.